# UNIDUINO HELP SWITCH CAMERA'S

Tags: c#, arduino, unity-game-engine

I need my script to go to the next camera every time I press a button on my Arduino, I just can't get it working can somebody please help me?

I got the Arduino communicating with Anity but i just can't get my head around the camera switching part.

Could someone tell me how to make a button press hop to the next camera, so I only need 1 button to show all the camera's

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Uniduino;

#if (UNITY_3_0 || UNITY_3_0_0 || UNITY_3_1 || UNITY_3_2 || UNITY_3_3 || UNITY_3_4 || UNITY_3_5)     
public class DigitalRead : Uniduino.Examples.DigitalRead { } // for unity 3.x
#endif

namespace Uniduino.Examples
{

    public class digitalread2 : MonoBehaviour {

        public Arduino arduino;

        public int pin = 2;
        public int pinValue;
        public int testLed = 11;
        public int licht;
        public int enable;
        public int val = 0;
        public GameObject cam1;
        public GameObject cam2;
        void Start () 
        {
            arduino = Arduino.global;
            arduino.Log = (s) => Debug.Log("Arduino: " +s);
            arduino.Setup(ConfigurePins);

            cam1 = GameObject.Find ("cam1");


        }

        void ConfigurePins ()
        {
            arduino.pinMode(pin, PinMode.INPUT);
            arduino.reportDigital((byte)(pin/8), 1);
            // set the pin mode for the test LED on your board, pin 13 on an Arduino Uno
            arduino.pinMode(testLed, PinMode.OUTPUT);

    }


        void Update () 
        {
             // read the value from the digital input
            enable = arduino.digitalRead (pin);
            licht = arduino.digitalRead (pin);
            pinValue = arduino.digitalRead(pin);
            // apply that value to the test LED
            arduino.digitalWrite(testLed,pinValue);
            Debug.Log(pinValue);

            val = arduino.digitalRead (pin);

            arduino.digitalWrite (testLed, val);
            val = cam1.active = false;

            val = cam2.active = true;



        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
GameObject cam1, cam2;
void Start(){
  cam1 = Find("camera_name");
  cam2 = Find("camera2_name");
  cam1.enabled = True;
  cam2.enabled = False;

void Update(){
  if(Input.GetButtonDown... // you need to  implement ur arduino && cam1,isActive())
      cam1.enabled = false;
      cam2.enabled = true;
  if(Input.GetButtonDown... // you need to  implement ur arduino && cam2.isActive()) {
      cam2.enabled = false;
      cam1.enabled = true;
}
```

There might be something wrong. I am not able to use Unity Tool now. I am also not sure if you can you "cam1.enabled" or not.